# Proper settings for socket.io flash (and other) fallbacks for clients using a proxy

Tags: node.js, proxy, websocket, socket.io

Salam (means hello) :)

I have the following basic settings in my node.js application. But it doesn't work for clients who are connected using a proxy or are behind a firewall. I want to know what should I add to get socket.io fallback to work as expected:

**Server side:**

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(3000, {
    log: 3,
    flashPolicyServer: true,
    transports: ['htmlfile', 'xhr-polling', 'jsonp-polling', 'flashsocket']
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function(){
    // my event handlers
});
```

**Client side:**

```
WEB_SOCKET_SWF_LOCATION = "oath/to/my/copy/of/WebSocketMain.swf";
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
// my event handlers
```

Answer (score 0):

Set flashsocket in transport

> - transports defaults to websocket, htmlfile, xhr-polling, jsonp-polling
>
> An array of allowed transport methods. The flashsocket transport is disabled by default, and can be enabled by setting the transports with the flashsocket option included.

Docs:
https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/Configuring-Socket.IO

Comment: but I've done that! as you can see in my question, the last field of `transport` array is `flashsocket`. any other suggestion?